# JPopupMenu display under Canvas

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, jpopupmenu

I have a Canvas, some text fields and a context menu.

When I start the application and right click on the canvas a popup menu shows. But when I write something inside the text field than I right click on the canvas, the popup will shows behind the canvas.

Any idea how to fix that ?

Comment: put up some code, ideally an SSCE. Usually, just by writing an SSCE you will find your issue.

Comment: http://sscce.org/, sorry I missed a C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled( false );
```

solved the issue.

Comment: This call affects all popup menus that will be created in future. Usually it is enough to modify `lightWeightPopupEnabled` property of the particular JPopup instance by calling `popup.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 3):

1) `Canvas` is `AWT Component`, and is `Heavyweight type of Components`

2) `JPopupMenu` is `Swing JComponent` and is `Lightweight type of JComponents`

3) possible to solve that by using `Swing JPanel` rather than `AWT Canvas`

4) your issue is about [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) or [rest is here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/)

Comment: I need a Heavyweight component to draw into it with opengl.

Comment: agreed correct way for OpenGL, your choice is more simpler than use JPopup use Window or un_decorated Dialog, there you can put Swing JButtons, for laying use GridLayout

Comment: Uggh.. adding replies before I've had my coffee is pointless. +1

Comment: @Andrew Thompson maybe your insomnia :-)